# Is there any way to copy EKEvent, or let it conform NSCopying protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ekevent, nscopying

I keep an instance of EKEvent and want to copy it. But I found EKEvent doesn't conform NSCopying protocol, so I try to add a category to EKEvent to let it conforms this protocol, however, eventIdentifier is a read-only attribute, so, this method failed.

Any way to do so?

Comment: It'll be nearly impossible to correctly add `NSCopying` support to a class for which you can't read the full implementation. You'll have no way to know whether you've copied private information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying an EKEvent object is maybe not necessary. 
At first I want to make sure my new Custom class object is absolutely a copy of another one.
However, what should do is create a new EKEvent object use this method.

`- (EKEvent *)eventWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

Make sure you keep the original EventStore object and use same EKCalendar.